# PostgreSQL query to rename and change column type with single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL if I need to rename and change a column data type, I run two separate queries to do so.

To rename:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tblName RENAME <oldColumn> TO <newColumn>
```

and to change column type:

```
ALTER TABLE tblName ALTER COLUMN <newColumn> <columnType>.
```

But is there any way to do both of these works with a single query like the following MySQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE tblName CHANGE COLUMN <oldColumn> <newColumn> <columnType>
```

Comment: I've removed the references to MS SQL Server. These sorts of "how do I do this on these different DBs" questions rarely lead to a single useful definitive answer. Please post a new, separate question for MS-SQL Server and link to it here. It would also be useful to know why you want to do this in the first place, as in this case there's no benefit to using a single `ALTER TABLE` statement vs two within the same transaction.

Comment: @dude When editing, please don't use `backticks` for emphasis. If you need to emphasise a piece of text, wrap it in `**two asterisks**`

Comment: @dude You appear to have reverted/ignored my edit - why?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, `ALTER TABLE` can take a series of operations. So:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> RENAME <oldcolumn> TO <newcolumn>;
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN <columnname> TYPE <newtype>;
```

is the same as

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> 
  ALTER COLUMN <columnname> TYPE <newtype>
  RENAME <oldcolumn> TO <newcolumn>;
```

However... why? IIRC the rename won't cause a full-table scan, so there's no benefit over just doing the two statements separately, within one transaction. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: What about SQL Server? Is it possible in SQL server too?

Comment: @taufique Please see my first comment on your question. It's best not to post "how do I do X in this list of databases" questions, because different people's expertise differs. See the comment on your post. I have no idea if it's possible on SQL server. Posting a separate question for SQL Server would be appropriate; then post a link to it here. But again - **why do you want to do this in the first place, when it makes no difference?**

Comment: You cannot use `RENAME` together with other actions in a single `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: Poor choice of example then, oops.

Comment: BTW, the most likely actual reason to do this rather than a series of separate alter table statements in a single txn is to optimise table rewrites, so multiple operations that would require a table rewrite can be done in one pass.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is because it is too old, this way of writing is definitely not applicable to the current postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL: Alter table column name and data-type:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName> 
   ALTER [ COLUMN ] column [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]
  RENAME [ COLUMN ] column TO new_column;
```

See [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).