# How to change a column name of a table in database using PSQL?

Tags: linux, psql

When I'm using command:

```
testing_psql_db=# alter column "phn_no" rename to phone_no;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "column"
LINE 1: alter column "phn_no" rename to phone_no;
```

How to change a column name of a table in database using PSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL query to rename and change column type with single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398603/postgresql-query-to-rename-and-change-column-type-with-single-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertable.html

You need the table name, the proper syntax is

```
alter table NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE rename column "phn_no" to phone_no;
```